# Wkhtmltopdf error in qweb report odoo 8 when print out pdf

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf, qweb

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
>  return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 517, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 283, in _call_function
>  return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
>  return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 280, in checked_call
>  return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 733, in __call__
>  return self.method(*args, **kw)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
>  response = f(*args, **kw)
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 144, in check_wkhtmltopdf
>  return request.registry['report']._check_wkhtmltopdf()
> File "/home/frontiir/gitlap/isp-erp/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 100, in __getitem__
>  return self.models[model_name]
> KeyError: 'report'
> ```

wkhtmltopdf version is 0.12.1.But I cann't print out pdf in Odoo 8.It might be becase of wkhtmltopdf version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.wkhtmltopdf version is Ok.It is problem in odoo base code.In openerp.module.request.registery don't know 'report' model.This report and code works for others.That is why I change new odoo base version 8 code.Some bugs in base code.